# How do I modify/append a table row using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

What I know is that you can append values from a query using concat function in MYSQL.

```
>col1 = ben

UPDATE table set col1 = concat(col1, ' altered')

>col1 = ben altered
```

But what I am trying to achieve is to append anywhere on the col.

```
col1 = ben

UPDATE table set col1 = "altered " + col1
-- pseudo code

col1 = altered ben
```

Is there a function for this in mysql?

Comment: is not clear you want add "altered " before the column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want  add before the column simply change the concat sequence

```
UPDATE table set col1 =  concat('altered ' , col1 )
```

You can se concat with all the column and value you prefer

```
 concat('altered ' , col1, ' altered')

 concat('altered ' , col1, ' altered', col2, col3, 'altered again')
```

Comment: can i do this? `concat('altered ' , col1, ' altered')`